# finding polarization of radiated far-zone electric field

Tags: antenna, electromagnetic, far-field

I am given a question in which I have to find the polarization of the radiated far-zone electric fields when phi is 0 and 90. Why are the following formulas used respectively?
For phi = 0
$$     E_\theta = jn\frac{kI_0le^{-jkr}}{4\pi r} cos\theta               $$

For phi = 90

$$     E_\theta = jn\frac{kI_0le^{-jkr}}{4\pi r} . 1               $$

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE - what has your own research shown and what specifically do you not understand?

Comment: @PeterSmith, sorry i wanted to find for phi 0 and 90 respectively.